# IE8 Rendering Incorrectly (not just CSS/HTML hack)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8

That sounds familiar I'm sure, but it's not a CSS hack issue.

I'm literally having trouble with a version of IE that is rendering a page completely different than another (same) version of IE8 on a different computer. I've checked the display settings, encoding, and zoom options on the afflicted computer. Interestingly it is also printing incorrectly.

The anomalies include, but aren't limited to incorrect margins, incorrect font sizing, incorrect line height.

The operating system is Windows XP. The browser is IE8.

Thoughts?

-JKT

Comment: Have you declared a valid DOCTYPE?

Comment: Yes. I don't believe this has to do with markup. I think it's specific to the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure compatibility mode is consistent between the 2 computers, i.e. probably want it on for both.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across similar problems and they seemed to have been caused by browser add-ons and/or toolbars.  In two cases I found, it was the "Ask" toolbar. Disabling the add-on didn't work, it had to be completely uninstalled and I had to reset Internet Explorer's settings in the Advanced Internet Options section.

Unfortunately, I have no idea why or how these add-ons changed the way IE renders some websites.

Answer (score 0):

Check accessibility settings these can affect text size and other factors which can lead to the problems you're experiencing.